# Sending data from A application to B application in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two separate applications.

How can I establish communication between these two applications like application A communicates with the other application B:

//Application  A MainActivity

```
String hai ="Hello";
Intent i = new Intent("com.gpstrackdefault");
i.putExtra("Act_Main", Killme);
//i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
//i.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(i);
```

//Application B Mainactivity

```
Intent intent =getIntent();
String action =intent.getAction();
String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra("Act_Default");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sharedText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.i("Extact text",sharedText);
```

//  B manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.gpstrackdefault.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"  
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter >
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Google cloud messaging, example [GCM](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line in your Activity B

```
String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra("Act_Default");
```

with

```
String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra("Act_Main");
```

Comment: isn't he asking about data transfer between two applications? instead of activities?

Comment: although i was also bit confused with the question he put and explanation he gave.I just corrected the mistake that he was doing in current code